"1" in $G$ or "1" in $Aut(G)$
"The automorphism $\alpha$ of group $G$ is called an automorphism without fixed points when any arbitrary element $g\neq1$ in $G$ implies $\alpha(g)\neq g$. If $G$ is a finite group and it has an automorphism $\alpha$ without fixed points, and also $\alpha^2=1$, then proof that $G$ is an Abelian group of odd order."
In this question, two "1" may have different meanings. The frst "1" must be "1" in $G$, the second "1" is probably "1" in $Aut(G)$. But what if the second "1" means "1" in $G$?Will the different understandings lead to different answers?
(The question is a slightly ambiguous practice in a Chinese book.)
Edit：The second understanding means $\alpha(g)^2=1$. (In fact it is a falsification of the question. Some newbeginner may have this and give their strange proof. I just wonder if it is provable in the second understanding)

This would be a type error. You cannot say that an automorphism of G is an element of G. I have no idea what you are asking.

Since $\alpha^{2} = \alpha \circ \alpha \in Aut(G)$ and you said $\alpha^{2} = 1$, you cannot consider the second "$1$" as an element in $G$.

@ShuningZhang The other understanding means $\alpha(g)^2=1$. Since $\alpha(g) \in G$, the operation is on group $G$, and $1$ can be $1\in G$

@MartinBrandenburg The question you have is the similar one.

You could interpret the equation $\alpha^2 = 1$ as equality to the constant function $g\mapsto 1$, and then you could easily show this implies $G$ is the trivial group.
Similarly you could interpret the square as element-wise group multiplication and get yet another implication.


New question: Let $G$ be a finite group, $\alpha$ an automorphism of $G$ s.t. $(\alpha(g))^{2}=1_{G}$ for all $g \in G$, then what can we say about $G$ ?

Since $\alpha$ is surjective, we can derive that $g^2=1_G$ for all $g \in G$, i.e., $g^{-1} = g$ for all $g \in G$.
Now, it's easy to see that the inverse map $Inv_G: G \to G, g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is equal to $id_G$.
Since $Inv_G \in End(G) \Leftrightarrow G$ is abelian (You can find a proof at here), we can derive that $G$ is abelian.
Furthermore, we can make the algebraic structure of $G$ more clear:
Since every element of $G$ is of order $2$, we derive that $2$ is the only prime divisor of $|G|$, and so $|G|=2^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$.
Because

$G$ is abelian;
$g^2=1_G$ for all $g \in G$;
$|G|=2^n$,

$G$ is naturally a $2$-dim vector space over field $\mathbb{F}_2$, and so $Aut(G) \cong GL_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$.
Now, we are clear about what $G$ and $Aut(G)$ are.
